# docker run $PATH issue with minikube / kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have been trying to get one of my containers running locally with minikube [I am still quite new to all of this FYI]. 
Prior to building the container I have been running eval $(minikube docker-env) and I can see the 'new' container listed when I run docker images.

Here is my docker file for reference:

```
# start with python base
FROM python:3.6.4

# whom to come after if things break
LABEL maintainer="my_email_address"

# add tests to container
ADD . /app

ENV APP_PATH=/app

# set working directory
WORKDIR $APP_PATH

# install requirements for tests
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# clear all cached files
RUN find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf

# set env variables
ENV TEST $TEST \
USERNAME $USERNAME \
PASSWORD $PASSWORD \
USERNAME2 $USERNAME2 \
PASSWORD2 $PASSWORD2 \
AUTH_TOKEN_1 $AUTH_TOKEN_1 \
AUTH_TOKEN_2 $AUTH_TOKEN_2

# type of command
CMD pytest $TEST

# clean up
RUN rm -rf /tmp/* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I then created this yml file for minikube, and at the end include a docker run command to pass in some env variables the container is expecting.

build.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: api-test-pod-k
spec:
 containers:
 - name: api-test-container-k
   image: api-test-container-k
   imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
   command: ["docker run -e USER=root -e USERNAME='email@address.com' -e PASSWORD='xxxx' -e USERNAME2='email2@address.com' -e PASSWORD2='xxxx' -e AUTH_TOKEN_1='XXXXXX' -e AUTH_TOKEN_2='XXXXXX' -e TEST='test_* -m smoke' api-test-container-k"]
```

When I attempt to deploy the pod it end up in the status of

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                           READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
api-test-pod-k                 0/1       RunContainerError   0          14s
```

and the logs show the following:

```
kubectl logs -f api-test-pod-k
container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker run -e USER=root -e USERNAME='email@address.com' -e PASSWORD='xxxx' -e USERNAME2='email2@address.com' -e PASSWORD2='xxxx' -e AUTH_TOKEN_1='XXXXXX' -e AUTH_TOKEN_2='XXXXXX' -e TEST='test_* -m smoke' api-test-container-k\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

What has me confused is that I can run this docker command locally without minikube in the mix there are no issues. Why would minikube / K8 treat this differently?

I know this is a lot of info. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't seem to be correct:

`command: ["docker run -e USER=root ...`

In that `command` section in your yaml, you can override the `CMD` line from your Dockerfile, but it's optional. Normally, you don't want to do that. In your case, you are trying to run the `docker run` inside your container and the error you are seeing is saying it can't find the `docker` command on your `$PATH` in the image.

Also it's a good practice to have the `CMD pytest $TEST` or `ENTRYPOINT` as the very last line in your dockerfile. For start, you can use some linter for dockerfiles, for instance [this one](https://www.fromlatest.io).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the linter link.